# MSSQL Добавление атрибутов в таблицу при выгрузке

Tags: sql, sql-server

Столкнулся с интересной ситуацией.
Нужно выгружать одинаковые по структуре таблицы с разных БД в свою локальную БД,  при этом для каждой выгружаемой таблицы присваивать по 2 поля ID и DATE:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1   
    (  
        ID_TBL AS '1 ',   
        UNLOAD_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT default_name DEFAULT  getdate()
    );
```

Можно ли это использовать в конструкции?:

```
SELECT * INTO local_table FROM Remote_table;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста  как ещё можно реализовать задумку?

Comment: Select into создает новую таблицу. Если таблица уже есть с таким именем, будет ошибка.
Используйте insert into в таком случае.  Ну, и число столбцов должно быть одинаковым. Например,
insert into local_table select '1', getdate(), * from remote_table;

Comment: А как добавить доболнительные столбцы содержашие -  '1', getdate(), к сушествующим сточкам данных?

Comment: Если изначально локальной таблицы нет, используйте для первой удаленной таблицы select into, создавая необходимые столбцы, а для второй insert into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте документацию по [`INSERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) ([на русском](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174335(v=sql.120).aspx)). Приблизительное решение для вашего случая:

```
-- создаем таблицу для импорта
CREATE TABLE dbo.Destination_Table (
   Source_Table_ID      INT      NOT NULL,
   Unload_Date          DATE     NOT NULL    DEFAULT getdate(),
   -- перечисление столбцов из таблиц источников
   Column1              INT      NOT NULL,
   Column2              DATETIME NULL,
   ....
   ColumnN              INT      NOT NULL
   );

-- импорт первой таблицы
INSERT INTO dbo.Destination_Table (
   Source_Table_ID,
   -- столбец Unload_Date не упоминаем, ему присваивается стандартное значение
   Column1,
   Column2,
   ...
   ColumnN)
SELECT
   -- прописываем идентификатор таблицы источника
   1 AS Source_Table_ID
   Column1,
   Column2,
   ...
   ColumnN
FROM Source_Table1;

-- импорт второй таблицы
INSERT INTO dbo.Destination_Table (
   Source_Table_ID,
   Column1,
   Column2,
   ...
   ColumnN)
SELECT
   2 AS Source_Table_ID
   Column1,
   Column2,
   ...
   ColumnN
FROM Source_Table2;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это мне очень помогло. Документацию прочёл!